# The intervals generating the Cantor set form a net

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I found a remark on Falconer's *The Geometry of Fractal Sets*. The topic is the construction of the Cantor set
$$C=\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{j=1}^{2^k} I_{k{ }j},$$
where the intervals $I_{kj}$ are as pictured:

[image: Cantor contrusction - Taken from Mattila, Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean space]

The book says that those intervals form a 'net' in the sense that for any pair of them, either they are disjoint or one is included in the other.

Is there some connection to the concept of [net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) of topology, that is, a function defined on a directed set?

(I think that there is no connection, and it is only a notational coincidence, but I am not sure.)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I can’t see any real connection. I’ve never seen the term *net* used this way; I’d have said simply that if $\mathscr{I}$ is the family of intervals in question, $\langle\mathscr{I},\supseteq\rangle$ is a tree. Indeed, if you replace these intervals by their intersections with the Cantor set, you have what is called *tree base* for the topology of the Cantor set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I find your comment useful. Could you convert it into an answer, please? This way I'll be able to upvote it.

Comment: Sure; hang on a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t see any real connection. I’ve never seen the term *net* used this way; I’d have said simply that if $\mathscr{I}$ is the family of intervals in question, $\langle\mathscr{I},\supseteq\rangle$ is a tree. Indeed, if you replace these intervals by their intersections with the middle-thirds Cantor set, you have what is called a *tree base* for the topology of the Cantor set.

Comment: Indeed a tree base is exactly what the OP formulated: two members are either disjoint (in different branches of the tree) or one is contained in the other (when they are in the same branch). I haven't seen net used for this either.